# HTML/Javascript: Im trying to retrieve an especific checkbox value inserted in a table

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I need to obtain the value from a matrix cell which is not unique.
This model is a simplification of the original model which is a huge matrix and 
that is why I put enfasis on this: 
document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0].**XXXXXX**.

Objetive: What property or method should I use in that instruction to obtain the value of a checkbox (true/false) or (1,0).

Thank you!!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Tratando de obtener valores de los checkbox dentro de una tabla.</p>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td id='C1'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked'> </td>
        <td id='C2'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked'> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='C3'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked'> </td>
        <td id='C4'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked'> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p id="print1"></p>
  <p id="print2"></p>
  <p id="print3"></p>
  <p id="print4"></p>

  <br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Intentarlo</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0];

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checked/unchecked state of a checkbox is stored in its [`checked`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) property. Note that the `cell` you're getting is a `td`, not an `input`—you need to get the `td`'s (cell's) child element that is an `input` (for safety, I'm using `querySelector`; if the `input` is always the nth child, you could use `children[n]` (where `n` is 0-based)). See below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0].querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Trying to obtain values from checkboxes within a table.</p>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td id='C1'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked'> </td>
      <td id='C2'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked'> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='C3'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked'> </td>
      <td id='C4'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked'> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p id="print1"></p>
  <p id="print2"></p>
  <p id="print3"></p>
  <p id="print4"></p>

  <br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>

</body>

</html>
```